# Как правильно выполнить условие работы скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно добавить условие, при котором скрипт срабатывал бы только при ширине окна не менее, например, 1500px? Спасибо!

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.fixed-div');
    $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
            $nav.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $nav.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fixed-box {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.fixed-div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
}
html {height:1000px; padding-top:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-box">
    <div class="fixed-div">
        Блок
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так можно определить ширину. Соответственно в вашем случае надо функцию поместить в условие `if` по ширине.

```
window.innerWidth // вся ширина окна
document.documentElement.clientWidth // ширина минус прокрутка
```

На вашем примере

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  if(window.innerWidth>1500) {
    $nav = $('.fixed-div');
    $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
  };
});
```

Comment: @LADYX сделал..

Comment: @LADYX кроме того не обязательно все переменные называть начиная с $.